# Improving query response speed when joining a non-spatial table with a spatial table on a non-spatial column

Tags: sql-server, query-performance, sql-server-2014, execution-plan, spatial

I have a table of frequently updating events that affect certain geometries. The geometry areas are fixed, but there may be an event affecting multiple areas at once, so there's a many-to-many relationship between the two. A single area may also be affected by multiple events at the same time.

For example:

| Event ID | Area ID |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 15 |
| 1 | 31 |
| 2 | 46 |
| 3 | 46 |
| 3 | 55 |
| 4 | 15 |

The areas are represented in my table as ID values. I need to represent these spatially, so I need to join the `event_id` `and area_id` values to a lookup table that contains the `area_id`s and the geometry. Unfortunately, the tables are in two separate databases on the same SQL Server 2014 instance.

The problem is that this join process is quite slow; it takes anywhere from 90 seconds to 3 minutes to return 18k-24k rows, depending on how many events are active at the moment. The geometry lookup table contains 84k rows.

The events table structure (some additional columns removed for simplicity's sake):

```
USE Events_DB;
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Events](
    [EVENTS_ID] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [AREA_ID] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [START_DATE_TIME] [smalldatetime] NULL,
    [END_DATE_TIME] [smalldatetime] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Events] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [EVENTS_ID] ASC,
    [AREA_ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

The geometry lookup table structure:

```
USE Geom_DB;
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Area_Geom](
    [AREA_ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Geom] [geometry] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [Area_Geom] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [AREA_ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
```

My query is below. I'm using a CTE for the event and area IDs because they're being used in elsewhere in the full query, but I've narrowed down the bottleneck to this particular portion.

```
WITH active_ids (EVENTS_ID, AREA_ID) AS (SELECT DISTINCT EVENTS_ID, AREA_ID
        FROM EVENTS
        WHERE END_DATE_TIME > getUTCdate())

SELECT geom FROM Area_Geom WHERE area_id IN (SELECT area_id FROM active_ids);
```

[The execution plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=HkmmzfQTj) shows that the clustered index scan of the primary key index on the Area_Geom table; it's taking nearly 2 minutes to scan through the ~84k rows stored in that table.

I threw this question at one of our company DBAs and he was stumped. Can I do anything else to find some performance improvements? I know the cross-database portion of the join is part of the problem, and I can't do anything about that, unfortunately.

I did note that the two `Area_ID` values on the two tables are of two different types (bigint and int); however, casting the Area_ID within the CTE to int made little difference in performance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### ⛈️⛈️⛈️

Good news! Your query finishes rather quickly!

[image: NUTS]

Bad news! It takes a long time to get do *other stuff*.

[image: NUTS]

Given the long elapsed time here when compared to CPU, you can bet that the query was either blocked, or receiving the results took a long time.

If you run the same query and dump it into a #temp table so that you're not returning results to SSMS, that should help determine if the bottleneck is server-side or client-side.

```
WITH 
    active_ids AS 
(
    SELECT DISTINCT 
        e.AREA_ID
    FROM [EVENTS] AS e
    WHERE END_DATE_TIME > GETUTCDATE()
)
SELECT
    a.*
INTO #active_ids
FROM active_ids AS a;

SELECT 
    a.geom 
INTO #Area_Geom
FROM Area_Geom AS a
WHERE area_id IN (SELECT ai.area_id FROM #active_ids AS ai);

SELECT
    ag.*
FROM #Area_Geom AS ag;
```